# Delete query not woking SQL c#

Tags: c#, mysql, delete-row

i have been trying to delete rows from a table but the code i wrote isn't working, i'm not sure if it is the SQL syntax or the code itself, visual studio isn't throwing any errors it just launches the program without any trouble, after i click the button to delete, the program freezes and i'm unable to even close it.
If i check the database after doing this it remain untouched.

Also i'm sorry if i don't explain very well, English is not my mother language so its a bit hard for me, thank you in advance.

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("DOING STUFF");
        bool check = true;
        do
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\wintouch;Initial Catalog=bbl;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd";
            string queryString = string.Empty;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                queryString = "DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' tipodoc ='FSS' AND and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -2, getdate())),120) ";                    
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                //command.Connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                queryString = "SELECT * FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' tipodoc ='FSS' AND and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -2, getdate())),120) ";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        check = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        check = false;
                        MessageBox.Show("STILL DOING STUFF");
                    }
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        while (check);
```

Comment: missing an `and` here : `WHERE serie ='1' tipodoc ='FSS'`

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much the answer, syntax error, i'm sorry been working on this code the whole night it's taking the toll on me.

Comment: all good - trick is to focus on the sql and debug it in the client ( if not clear )

Comment: Test your query in sql management studio first then move to code, and use sql parameters to avoid sql injections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you think how SQL commands work, but they surely aren't asynchronous, so you neither need the loop nor the second `using` block which checks whether the lines you just deleted are still there. The delete process will end only after all lines have been deleted.

Also the code you posted can not be the real code, as you should be getting an SQL exception due to invalid syntax in your `WHERE` clause.

So your code can be shortened to the following (fixing the `WHERE` clause, too):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("DOING STUFF");

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\wintouch;Initial Catalog=bbl;User ID=sa;Password=Pa$$w0rd";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string queryString = "DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' tipodoc ='FSS' AND and contribuinte ='999999990' and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -2, getdate())),120) ";                    
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline query is not correct for both `DELETE` and `SELECT`. Corrected query will be like the following.

Delete query

```
DELETE FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' AND tipodoc ='FSS' AND contribuinte ='999999990' 
 and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -2, getdate())),120)
```

Select query

```
SELECT * FROM wgcdoccab WHERE serie ='1' AND tipodoc ='FSS' AND    contribuinte ='999999990' 
and  datadoc = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd, -2, getdate())),120)
```